# Is there one word for "abruptly turning around"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, verbs

I'm looking for a stronger verb for *"she abruptly turned around"*. In this scene I'm writing, my character is frozen in place, observing something disturbing, but then she turns around abruptly to leave the scene.

Comment: How about "spun round"?

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! I thought about that one as well, but I'm looking for a word that conveys more determination, if that makes sense. Personally, I would use "spun around" in action scenes or when the character is surprised or startled by something.

Comment: She "swung round"?

Comment: "She whipped around"? Any faster and she'll take off like a helicopter.

Comment: How about _pirouette_?

Comment: _Do a 180_ is a term I've frequently heard. You have to be in motion, though.

Comment: How about *about-face* as a verb? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

How about the well-known idiom, "turned on her heels"?
(Alternatively, "spun on her heels".)

One-word adjectives might not give the same visual impact as a more colourful idiom or even the use of a metaphor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).